# Code crashes at runtime with Absoft Fortran but not with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm running a script that starts similar to the code below. In the past when I ran the script `f90 -o fakefile fakefile.f` and then `./fakefile` it worked, but now it does not and immediately returns a `segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. When I use `gfortran fakefile.f` and then `./a.out` the code runs fine. I cannot figure out what the discrepancy is between using the two compiling methods.

```
 program fakefile
   implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
   parameter(im9=4320,jm9=2160)
   parameter(im1=360,jm1=180)
   parameter(im25=1440,jm25=720)
   parameter(nlt=2)
   real*4 rrs(im9,jm9,nlt)
   real*8 rrsa25(im25,jm25,nlt)
   real*8 area25(im25,jm25,nlt)
   real*8 rrsa1(im1,jm1,nlt)
   real*8 area1(im1,jm1,nlt)
   rrsa1  = 0.0
   area1  = 0.0
   rrsa25 = 0.0
   area25 = 0.0
   rrs = 0.0
   print *, rrs

 end
```

Comment: Do you have any idea which line causes the problem? take out the statements one by one until you find the offending one. So how does the screen look when trying to print 9,331,200 zero reals? Maybe change the size of the arrays to also for checking.

Comment: @ja72 It seems the program doesn't like: real*4 rrs(im9,jm9,nlt), is the array size greater than f90 allows? I haven't had this problem until now and i've used similar scripts with the same array size.

Comment: What compiler is `f90` using (try `f90 -v` to see)?  gfortran is a Fortran 90 (95/2003/2008) compiler.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing! I have seen systems where `f90` even was a link to `gfortran`. You are talking about a script called `f90`... Could you post the script?

Comment: @casey It returns: Absoft 64-bit Pro Fortran 11.5.2. I think I may have figured out my problem to be the stacksize limit on the server. Doing limit in c shell returns: stacksize   10240 kbytes

Comment: does `f90 -s -o fakefile fakefile.f` produce a working program?

Comment: @casey yes it does! What does the -s flag do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segmentation fault is due to overlowing the stack with your large arrays.  This is a common issue on Absoft and Intel Fortran compilers.  For your compiler (Absoft), use the `-s` flag to tell the compiler to allocate arrays on the heap instead of the stack.  The alternative is to increase your stack size limit in your shell (which may be restricted by the administrator).

See the Absoft FAQ: [When I declare large arrays (>8 MB of variables), I get a
segmentation violation from Linux.](http://www.absoft.com/Support/FAQ/V10.0Linux3264bit.html#anchor0011)

> A. Use the "-s" compiler option (static storage) to move
>   the data from the stack to the heap or use the ulimit
>   command (ulimit is a bash command - the csh equivalent to
>   'ulimit -s' is 'limit stack') to raise the stack size limit
>
> # ulimit -s 8192
>      # ulimit -s 32768
>      # ulimit -s 32768
>
> Once raised the limit applies to the current
>   process and any children of that process.